# The result of a scalar fullselect more than one row when trying to update set values

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

So i'm trying to set values of Overtime_Total. To calculate overtime_Total u need to multiply Overtime_hours (from table Overtime) and Overtime_Rate(from table Employee_type). Here's the problem , when i try to set the values by using the following command(command 1), i get The error as below. However when i use another command(Command) it show values matching to its ID.

Command 1

```
update Overtime
set Overtime_total = 
(SELECT (OVERTIME.OVERTIME_HOURS * EMPLOYEE_TYPE.OVERTIME_RATE)AS OVERTIME_TOTAL
FROM OVERTIME
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TYPE ON OVERTIME.EMP_TYPE_ID = EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMP_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN SALARY ON SALARY.SALARY_ID = OVERTIME.SALARY_ID);
```

COmmand 2

```
(SELECT Overtime.Overtime_ID,(OVERTIME.OVERTIME_HOURS * EMPLOYEE_TYPE.OVERTIME_RATE)AS OVERTIME_TOTAL
FROM OVERTIME
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TYPE ON OVERTIME.EMP_TYPE_ID = EMPLOYEE_TYPE.EMP_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN SALARY ON SALARY.SALARY_ID = OVERTIME.SALARY_ID);
```

Error

```
The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES
INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000
```

[Table Overtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7e9U.png)

[Table Employee_type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85WJK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give condition of main table id in subquery

```
 update Overtime ot 
    set Overtime_total = 
    (SELECT (t1.OVERTIME_HOURS * emp.OVERTIME_RATE)AS OVERTIME_TOTAL
    FROM OVERTIME t1
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TYPE emp ON t1.EMP_TYPE_ID = emp.EMP_TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN SALARY sal ON sal.SALARY_ID = t1.SALARY_ID where t1.EMP_TYPE_ID=ot.EMP_TYPE_ID and t1.overtime_id=ot.overtime_id);
```

You can also use `merge` which will be more faster than above method

```
merge into Overtime ot
using(
SELECT t1.overtime_id,t1.EMP_TYPE_ID,(t1.OVERTIME_HOURS * emp.OVERTIME_RATE)AS OVERTIME_TOTAL
FROM OVERTIME t1
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TYPE emp ON t1.EMP_TYPE_ID = emp.EMP_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN SALARY sal ON sal.SALARY_ID = t1.SALARY_ID) st
on ot.EMP_TYPE_ID=st.EMP_TYPE_ID and ot.overtime_id=st.overtime_id
when matched then update set ot.Overtime_total=st.OVERTIME_TOTAL;
```

Comment: change `OVERTIME.OVERTIME_HOURS to ot.OVERTIME_HOURS`. Worked . Thank you man

Comment: yeah changed it to `t1` instead of `to`